# How to make a loop for each sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a dictionary program, but have a problem when output results, I want the results of each sentence.

```
dict_file = """water=45 
melon=8 
apple=35 
pineapple=67 
I=43 
to=90 
eat=12 
tastes=100 
sweet=21 
it=80 
watermelon=98 
want=70
juice=88"""

conversion = {k: int(v) for line in dict_file.split('\n') for (k,v) in (line.split('='),)}

text = """I want to eat banana and watermelon
I want drink juice purple and pineapple
it tastes sweet pineapple"""

result= ', '.join(str(conversion[word]) for word in text.split() if word in conversion)

print(result)
```

Output :

```
43, 70, 90, 12, 98, 43, 70, 88, 67, 80, 100, 21, 67
```

I want to output :

```
43, 70, 90, 12, 98
43, 70, 88, 67
80, 100, 21, 67
```

Comment: you have to split text too using the `'\n'` and join the result. The `result` should be a *nested* `join` (`'\n'.join(', '.join(...))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text.split()` splits on *all* whitespace, obliterating your newlines.  First split on newlines (`'\n'`) then split on any remaining whitespace.  Rejoin what you split on whitespace with commas.  Rejoin what you split with newlines with newlines.

```
result = '\n'.join(
    ', '.join(str(conversion[word]) for word in line.split() if word in conversion) 
    for line in text.split('\n'))
```

You could change `str(conversion[word])` to `conversion[word]` if you change the definition of `conversion`:

```
# replaced int(v) with v.strip()
conversion = {k: v.strip() for line in dict_file.split('\n') for (k,v) in (line.split('='),)}
```

I would prefer this definition:

```
conversion = dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in dict_file.split('\n'))
```

Here's a variation that handles missing values differently:

```
result = '\n'.join(
    ', '.join(conversion.get(word, '--') for word in line.split())
    for line in text.split('\n'))
```

`print(result)` gives

```
43, 70, 90, 12, --, --, 98
43, 70, --, 88, --, --, 67
80, 100, 21, 67
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, readability is more important than brevity.

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
    s = ', '.join(str(conversion[word]) for word in line.split() if word in conversion)
    print(s)

# Output
'''
43, 70, 90, 12, 98
43, 70, 88, 67
80, 100, 21, 67
'''
```